# Can VMWARE Workstation read beyond 4GB memory in 32bit Windows host?

Tags: vmware-workstation, virtualization

Windows 32bit can only make use of ~3.2GB when 4GB is installed.

Some software such as Superspeed's Ramdisk can use the unused memory, that is, I can use the remaining wasted 768MB for ramdisk purpose.

Does VMWARE workstation have this feature? I would like to use the wasted memory for guest OSes in VMWARE, example I have 8GB installed, HOST Windows only sees 3.2GB, remaining 4.7GB used for VMs.

Reason I'm asking this is that I don't want switch to 64bit windows yet.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

I would say no since the OS you are running it on cant adress more then 3.x gb memory in a 32bit enviroment and the system need to be able to adress it in order to let applications use it.
Havnt tried it tho.

Answer (score 1):

The hardware feature you need to address anything over 4GB *in any way* from a system running 32bit Mode is called PAE. If this is not emulated by the virtual environment, then: No.

Answer (score 0):

On 32 bit win machine, the only one thing you may use the "upper" memory for - ram drive.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/server2_beta2_faq.pdf

Page 2, under "64-bit guest operating system support..."